# Bug? Notifications are flooded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Correct me if I am wrong, but my notifications are flooded from all sites I am in within the stackexchange network, have a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Seems normal to me. What did you expect?

Comment: I expected a "one time" notification, why I need to know the same thing 20+ times? Maybe it should be grouped somehow? Or maybe I am just missing the reason why I get also +100 reputation in all other sites. It is perhaps not a bug and meant to be to say somehow "thanks" to the active user, but all I can say it was confusing me a lot, resulting in this "is this a bug?" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. You have reached 200 reputation on one account for the first time (at GLU, in this case) and receive an *association bonus* of 100 for all of your accounts (including GLU). If you create a new account on another site, your reputation will start at 101 instead of 1.

All your sites giving you a notification may be a bit much, but most people don’t have that many accounts by the time they reach 200 on one of them. Also, it won’t happen again in the future.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, haven't found an info about this case, so I was confused if it is really the intention to give that bonus for all sites you are in, inclusive the sites you will join in the future.

Comment: @netsetter: The idea is that you already know how SE works in general and should be able to vote up, flag, use images etc. right away instead of having to earn these privileges again for each new site.

Comment: If you tell me this, it makes sense, but with only these notifications floods it wasn't clear to me. Maybe beside these bonus points, a new badge telling you that you are now an "expert" in using the stackexchange network would be perhaps a solution to slow understanding people like me :)

Comment: Or in addition, just a grouped notification message that you have received these bonus points for all sites you are in.

Comment: @netsetter: It would probably add complexity to the piece of software processing these notifications. You could open a feature request on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), if it is important to you; it seems noone has done so yet.

Comment: Technically it should be possible without a large impact to the network, but it's not that important to me I think to open a feature request, for now. Anyway, I found out that there's a bug with the 100 bonus reputation points, I joined a new site, have 101 reputation already, but can not reply to protected answers, it says that I need at least 10 reputation points to do so.

Comment: @netsetter: It seems that’s intentional, though I didn’t know about it either. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937

Comment: Okay great, understood. You seems to be already very experienced in using the stackexchange network, I have a question but I don't know where to put this question, it is a question about the stackexchange network in general, is there a place to ask such "offtopic" questions?

Comment: @netsetter: The right place for questions about SE in general is again [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Unlike the other Metas, it is not only the Meta for SO, but for the whole network. (Also for this reason, it has a separate reputation count.)

Comment: What I said in my previous comment was true at the time, but now there *is* a separate [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), and MSO is for SO only (old entries referring to the network were moved).

Comment: It is also incorrect that you gain a bonus 100 rep *in the Stack Exchange site that you just reached 200 rep in*. From when that happened to me, reaching 200 rep in GLU, that boosted my TeX-rep to above 200, and my notification in GLU said that TeX’s 200 rep caused +100 on GLU (while GLU caused +100 on all other sites I was on — Chemistry, Anime, Ask Ubuntu off the top of my head)